# Convert Csv To Picture

Tags: python, csv

So recently I built a scanner out of my old lego mindstorms set the file it out puts is in csv format and looks some thing like this

```
1,1,152
11,1,49
21,1,56
31,1,59
41,1,60
51,1,58
61,1,61
71,1,57
81,1,60
91,1,61
```

The first number is the x value of the pixel (1,490)
The second is the y value (1,870)
and the third is the light value (0,100)

My original idea was to use python to convert the file however I have no clue how to format it into a picture. So my question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an image library like [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/index.html), create a new Image object, then loop through your csv file, setting the pixels in the image object to their appropriate values.  Then you can save the image object into a traditional format, like PNG.

Comment: Thank you I will try that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the program I made if any one is interested

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import csv

out = Image.new("L",(49,87))
dout = ImageDraw.Draw(out)
import csv
with open('pic.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        dout.point((int(row[0]) / 10,int(row[1]) / 10),fill=int(int(row[2]) * 2.55))
        #print(row[0] + " " + row[1] + " " + row[2])
out.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this for others! :)

Comment: If any one need explanation please ask :)